# Confused by Node.js installation to use Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm going through the tutorial provided by Angular(https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) but I'm confused by the Node.js installation. I already have node installed globally on my mac. In the tutorial it states:

> The tutorial instructions, from now on, assume you are running all commands from within the angular-phonecat directory.

Is the tutorial assuming that I do not have Node.js installed on my local machine? Or are these instructions for installing Node.js into my project folder? https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial#install-node-js

When I run the command:

```
node --version
```

I get the result:

```
v7.4.0
```

And I get that result running the command in a new terminal as well.

Comment: based on the comments you have made, it seems like you aren't even reading what the tutorial says.  `install nodejs-legacy npm` is **only necessary on Debian**, where there ***might*** be a conflict.  It's not even an option on MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial assumes that node **is** installed but you are running any commands from inside the *angular-phonecat* directory.

i.e. in a terminal you should `cd` to the *angular-phonecat* directory and run whatever commands are instructed.

```
cd /path/to/angular-phonecat
node start
```

It sounds like your set up is fine but you should verify you are running a compatible version of NodeJS.

Comment: so do I need to run
brew install nodejs-legacy npm 
nodejs --version
npm --version  ???

Comment: @brandozz: you are probably fine with 7.4.0 but you might want to check. If you want or need to switch versions on the fly, I would recommend installing `n`. `npm install -g n` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have node installed correctly already.

The bit about being in the angular-phonecat directly is just making sure you are in the directory where the package.json file is.  When you run say `npm install` it will look in your current directory for a package.json file.  So the demo just wants to make sure when they tell you to run commands that you are in the right directory.

Comment: Following the tutorial, when I run brew install nodejs-legacy npm... I get the error: Error: No formulae found in taps.